# JSTL error (HTTP Status 404 - /JSTL/home)

Tags: jsp, redirect, jstl

I am trying to use redirect tag for directing index page to the home page residing in my web project's JSP folder. The hierarchy of my project is as under:

```
WEB-INF
     jsp
        home.jsp
index.jsp
```

I am using both the libraries jstl 1.2 and standard.jar
Following is the code of my index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="/tags/c" %>

<core:redirect url="/home"></core:redirect>
```

When i run the project i recieve the following error;

```
HTTP Status 404 - /JSTL/home
type Status report
message /JSTL/home
description The requested resource (/JSTL/home) is not available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in `/WEB-INF` are not public accessible (it's not available when you enter their address in browser address bar). The `<jsp:include>` and any servlets using `RequestDispatcher` are the only which can access them.

So if you have a controller servlet which is mapped on `/*` and dispatches the request as follows

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp" + request.getPathInfo() + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
```

then your `<c:redirect>` will work. But if you don't have such a controller, then you should use `<jsp:include>` or move the `home.jsp` into public webcontent (there where your `index.jsp` also is) and redirect to `home.jsp` instead.

---

Unrelated to the problem, the way you declared the JSTL taglib doesn't give me a strong feeling you're doing things the right way or reading the proper tutorials. I suggest you to take a look in our [JSTL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

Comment: wow ! thanks sir. I was thinking on the same lines but i wanted to be sure about this fact. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect to "/home.jsp", not just "/home".